# How to create tooltip top right, bottom right, top left , bottom left corners using primeng in Angular css?

Tags: angular, tooltip, primeng

How to create tooltip top right, bottom right, top left , bottom left corners using primeng in Angular css ?
using tooltipStyleClass
added stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tooltip-demo-6ryv5d?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Are you asking how to style them with CSS?

Comment: yes, But it should be dynamic (i mean i can reuse the same to any other div with different width)